# Python sh library: How to get a shell?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, python-3.x

I am writing a Python3 script that uses the `sh` library (http://amoffat.github.io/sh/index.html#). I would like to get a shell inside a Docker container (actually a psql prompt, but I can't even get a shell, so let's go with the simpler case).

```
import sys
from sh import sudo

sudo = sudo.bake('-E') # XXX: Preserve environment

def process_output(char, stdin):
    sys.stdout.write(char.encode())

# XXX: Some commands expect a TTY STDIN
out_kwargs = {'_out': process_output, '_out_bufsize': 0, '_tty_in': True}

# Try to get a shell. -i is for interactive and -t enables a psuedo-tty.
# container_id is a valid Docker container ID
sudo.docker.exec('-i', '-t', container_id, '/bin/bash', **out_kwargs)
```

The bash prompt comes up, but when I type a command and press enter, nothing happens. So either no input is going to the shell's stdin, or I am not seeing resulting stdout. I think it's the former. Passing `_in=sys=stdin` seems to work for some "initial" stdin, like input piped in before the program runs.

How can I direct stdin to go to this shell?

Thanks.

Comment: does `pty.spawn(['sudo', '-E', 'docker -i -t {container_id} /bin/bash'.format(container_id=pipes.quote(container_id))])` allow you to interact with the shell?

Comment: No, that gives `sudo: docker -i -t container_id /bin/bash: command not found`. (container_id is a valid container ID in the actual output.)

Comment: I assume that you could fix the docker command so that it would find `bash`. The question is about I/O (whether pseudo-terminals work in this case)

Comment: Right, I can fix the command so that it can find bash. (`sudo.docker.exec('-i', '-t', container_id, 'bash', **out_kwargs)`). This gives me a bash prompt, but I can't enter anything.

Comment: To simplify this even further, `sudo.bash(**out_kwargs)` gives the same result - a prompt, but stdin doesn't work.

Comment: I meant: fix `pty.spawn` invocation.

Comment: Yes. This, for example, works and lets me interact: `pty.spawn(['sudo', 'docker', 'exec', '-i', '-t', 'container_id', 'bash'])`

Comment: ok. It means there is a hope that `sh` command could be fixed in principle. Could you instruct `sh` to use (pseudo-)tty for all commands for stdin/stdout/stderr pipes?